# Does the .git folder actually contain your files?

Tags: git

In theory, if you backed up just the `.git` folder in a flash drive and some rouge user deleted all your project files in your PC, can you still restore your files from that `.git` folder in your flash drive?

Note: This is just for a local repo scenario, I understand you can pull from an online repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, most of it. The `.git` folder contains the complete repository history (all commits and their contents), as well as the staging area (things you've `git add`-ed but not yet committed).

Indeed, when Git servers store repositories, they use *just* the .git folder (a "bare" repository).

It doesn't, however, contain copies of miscellaneous files that you haven't yet *told* Git about. If you made some edits but did not `git add` them, they won't have been copied into .git/objects/ yet.

The way to extract the files is `git checkout -f` or `git checkout <paths>` (which will copy staging area to working tree).

Comment: If I have staged but uncommitted changes in my `.git` folder, and then perform a `git clone` on it, is there any way to checkout the formerly staged changes?

Comment: @xjcl: Do you mean you performed `git clone` _from_ that folder or _to_ it?

Comment: From (`git clone foo/.git newfolder`)

Comment: @xjcl: No; clone only transfers commits and branches – it does not transfer the staging area, nor configuration, nor reflogs (stashes), nor other internal Git files.

Answer (score 3):

The `.git` directory in a project will have enough information to restore any version in your commit history.

---

Just for fun, I ran this locally:

```
cd <my local repo>
rm -r *
ls     # nothing there
ls -la # some dot files/directories
git checkout .
ls     # my stuff is back!
```

All my stuff was back (except some uncommitted changes, compile output, etc) and then I immediately regretted this "fun" exercise

---

That said, the .git directory does contain enough information to restore your files and even your historical commits.

See: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

Comment: Refs aren't commits; they're branches (well, moveable commit labels). Logically each commit _does_ store every file in full, although the underlying storage format takes care of deduplication and compression invisibly to the rest of git.

Comment: Good point, I updated the wording. What I was trying to convey was that you still will have access to all your commits in history, but aren't storing every full file from your git history individually.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is what's known as a 'bare' repository.

In essence, the `.git` directory contains all the data on all the revisions tracked in that repository.  This includes all the data required to reconstruct the working directory for a checkout.

Because of this, if you will never access the individual files of a repository, but only ever clone the repository or push or pull from it, you can save a potentially large amount of space by just having the `.git` directory.